# Using Data Driven Pages to clip to data driven page extent without clipping points at border of extent in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, data-driven-pages, arcgis-10.6, map-book

I am creating a mapbook in ArcMap 10.6.1 using Data Driven Pages, and excluding data outside of the data driven feature specified. However, the points within the feature of interest always get clipped at the border of the polygon. I.e. I often get cut-off points as seen in the image below (the image represents a polygon with random points generated along its edge):

[image]

My ultimate question is how do I keep the point symbols from being cut off at the borders?

I should also note that I have three data frames: one inset, and two side-by-side maps. So the solution would need to affect at least two of the data frames.

---

This section is for those that need further explanation of how I got here:

I first turned on data driven pages using the **Data Driven Pages** toolbar and set up my data accordingly. I then went to **View** > **Data Frame Properties** > **Data Frame** tab > **Clip Options** box and changed the settings to **Clip to current data driven page extent**. I then clicked **Exclude Layers...** checking the layers I wanted to serve in my background. I did not check my points layer.

If you need any further details, feel free to ask.